# How to create custom user in esapi

Tags: java, esapi

How can I create my own user class with additional properties in it?
I tried to create my own user class by implementing `org.owasp.esapi.User` interface and added some extra properties.

```
public class MyUserClass implements User{
```

then I tried this

```
MyUserClass userClass=(MyUserClass) ESAPI.authenticator().getCurrentUser();
```

But getting this exception:

```
SecurityConfiguration for Logger.LogEncodingRequired not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultUser cannot be cast to com.bean.MyUserClass
```

I also tried to extend DefaultUser class but error was same.

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The "exception" you are posting is actually two different items: (1) a log message, and (2) an actual exception. And while these are different items altogether, they still stem from the same underlying issue.

Short answer: **You are forgetting to set your security configuration system property when your app initializes.** It should look something like this:

```
System.setProperty("org.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration",
    "org.you.yourapp.YourAppSecurityConfiguration");
```

Where `org.you.yourapp.YourAppSecurityConfiguration` is the name of a class you'll write that implements [`SecurityConfiguration`](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/SecurityConfiguration.html). Because you are failing to set this system property, when the following [`ESAPI`](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/ESAPI.html#securityConfiguration%28%29) code runs:

```
private static String securityConfigurationImplName =   
    System.getProperty("org.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration", 
    "org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration");
```

...then since you never set the property, ESAPI is selecting the [`DefaultSecurityConfiguration`](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultSecurityConfiguration.html) for you.

When this `DefaultSecurityConfiguration` goes to initialize ESAPI's internal logging system, the following method is called:

```
protected String getESAPIProperty( String key, String def ) {
    String value = properties.getProperty(key);
    if ( value == null ) {
        logSpecial( "SecurityConfiguration for " + key + " not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: " + def, null );
        return def;
    }

    return value;
}
```

The property it's looking for here is a boolean called `Logger.LogEncodingRequired`. So if you want this first message to go away, you need something like:

```
boolean logEncodingRequired = true; // or false, your choice
System.setProperty("Logger.LogEncodingRequired", logEncodingRequired);
```

That takes care of your first issue:

> SecurityConfiguration for Logger.LogEncodingRequired not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false

Your second issue is also a result of ESAPI choosing a `DefaultSecurityConfiguration` for you. This default configuration has an [`authenticator()`](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/ESAPI.html#authenticator%28%29) method that returns an instance of [`FileBasedAuthenticator`](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/reference/FileBasedAuthenticator.html). And as that javadoc link explains, you need to have a `users.txt` file on your runtime classpath that contains all the serialized information about your users. And, of course, the `FileBasedAuthenticator` returns instances of [`DefaultUser`](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultUser.html) which is why you're getting the 2nd issue (which is an actual exception):

> `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultUser cannot be cast to com.bean.MyUserClass`.

Because you can't cast the `DefaultUser` (passed back from the `FileBasedAuthenticator`) to your own `MyUser` class.

Confused? It's really not so bad. Just implement your own `SecurityConfiguration` and set it as a system property, and you will be all set. HTH.

Comment: I see that setting security configuration property is set in **[ESAPI.java](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/ESAPI.java)**. It may make me sound stupid but where should I put the statement
`System.setProperty("org.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration",
    "org.me.myapp.MyAppSecurityConfiguration");` ?